# Can't seem to redirect input in Terminal

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line

I'm having issues getting redirection to work in Terminal.  I'm in a C++ class where we have to create an application, then find that application in the Terminal and place a text file in the same folder. That text file then has to be used as the input to the Terminal application we created in C++.  So, after building my application and placing it and a .txt file in a folder, I open the Terminal, navigate to that directory, then use:

```
program < textfile
```

or more specifically in my case:

```
redirect < input.txt
```

but it doesn't work.  I keep getting: "-bash: redirect: command not found"

I'm using the method our teacher told us to use based on windows command line, but I'm betting its not the same format for Terminal on Mac. I've been googling the issue for about a week and still have not figured it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT:

Added a photo:

[image]

EDIT2:

[image]

Comment: If you are running a program you compiled and it's _not_ in `/bin/`, you have to use `./programName`. Try `./redirect < input.txt`. But I can't say for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Far less can go wrong if you pipe the input:

```
cat words.5.txt | /path/to/redirect
```

In your case, `./program` might be needed depending on where you are compiling things or omitting the path entirely. From your edit this should work too:

```
./redirect < words.5.txt
```

That bash error is due to the program not existing in `$PATH`

```
echo $PATH
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll give this a shot soon, I edited my post and added a photo of the terminal, not sure if that will help at all.  I compiled the C++ program with Xcode and then just saved a copy of the built program to my desktop in a generic folder so I didn't have to do a ton of directory navigating to get to that default location of the program that Xcode builds.

Comment: This solved half of my problem, got the input to work using the ./redirect < words.5.txt, but the program isn't running now.  My "redirect" application is just a test application I wrote to make sure that I could get redirection to work before I actually did the homework, which is much more laborious coding.  So the redirect program just mirrors the input so I know its working, but with the redirection, its giving the program the input now, but no output.  I added another photo in my original post that shows the program working when running it, but not outputting with redirection.

Comment: @joe_04_04 Best to wrap up the initial problem - accept an answer and then perhaps ask a follow on question. Also - take  moment to look at [help] since we don't do code level questions and you might look to stack overflow or another site if your program isn't running itself. The basics of bash scripting are on topic here which is what you needed to know to get things connected - data file to program file and to execute the program. best of luck with your journey and this problem set specifically.

Comment: Hey Mike, I'll accept the answer, but I do know that my code isn't the issue.  The program itself is the part I know the best, just not the Terminal command.  I'll ask the question again and see why output isn't working now after redirection.